# Алгоритмы распределения

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Поставили следующую задачу:
Есть два динамических списка, первый это список курьеров, второй список заказов за последние сутки. Необходимо эффективно распределить заказы по курьерам. А именно: каждый курьер имеет  время работы (со скольки - до скольки), грузоподъемность его автомобиля, и максимальный объем груза за одну перевозку. Заказы имеют соответствующие поля. Так собственно вопрос, как **эффективно** распределить? Проблема в том, если есть, например, несколько мелких заказов, подходящих по времени, то распределить их соответственно курьеру с небольшим объемом и грузоподъемностью автомобиля, а крупные заказы по другим курьерам. Но может случится так, что последний из распределяемых курьеров не может взять крупный заказ, т.к. не работает в это время, но работает в то время, когда нужно доставить, к примеру, 2 мелких, которые уже распределены. Тогда нужно каким-то образом перераспределить мелкие заказы на последнего, а крупный запилить к "мелкому" курьеру.
Собственно, помогите советом :)

Comment: Все еще актуально...

Comment: @Евгений Шилин, пока критерий эффективности (да, похоже и еще некоторые ограничения) у Вас определен *чисто интуитивно*.

Вообще же задача непростая.  Что-то из серии динамического программирования.

Comment: Похоже на линейное программирование, попробуйте покопать в сторону [симплекс-метода](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

Comment: avp, Ну как я понимаю эффективность здесь носит достаточно абстрактный характер, т.к на практике использовать эту систему распределения по-моему не получится. 
VladD, спасибо.

Comment: @VladD, а разве симплекс-метод годится для дискретной оптимизации?

Comment: @avp: Хм. Если немного подкрутить, то по идее должен подойти. Оптимум на непрерывном симплексе достигается в одной из вершин, а вот для дискретного случая по идее в одной из дискретных точек в непосредственной близости от вершины.

Или нет, я тут не уверен.

В любом случае, всё линейное программирование по идее и начиналось с таких вот задач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выбрать несколько подходов. Первый. Это задача о рюкзаке. Её придётся чуть-чуть модифицировать. Об обычной задаче о рюкзаке можно прочитать тут:

[Емакс1](http://e-maxx.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=512)

[Емакс2](http://e-maxx.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=62)

[Статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/222577/)

[Нирка](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5)

[Информатикс](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=815&chapterid=60)

[Codeforces](http://codeforces.ru)

[Тимус](http://timus.ru)

Я бы советовал взглянуть на Информатикс. Мало того, что Вы можете прочитать годную теорию там с примерами. Помимо этого вы можете попробовать написать задачу и сдать её в тестирующую систему. На этом же сайте можно найти в [примерах задач](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=656) разборы решений, опубликованные кем-либо. Здесь можно найти как что-нибудь дельное, так и не очень. Но сюда тоже стоит заглянуть. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Разбор открывается при нажатии на синюю надпись "разбор", расположенную под названием задачи.

Codeforces.ru и timus.ru -- здесь можно найти задачи на различную тематику ДП. В том числе и рюкзак.

Что касается метода Гомори. То в интернете полно онлайн-решателей, с помощью которых можно разобраться с ходом действий. Более подробно можно прогуглить в интернете книгу Пантелеева И Летовой. Есть два издания. В одном написано чуть подробнее, в другом -- чуть менее. [Здесь](http://mybrary.ru/users/personal/read/metodyi-optimizatsii/) и [Здесь](http://www.alleng.ru/d/math-stud/math-st888.htm). Метод Гомори позволяет решить Вашу задачу в целых числах. Это тот же самый симлекс-метод, который перебирает вершины многомерного многоугольника. После этого в окрестностях полученных точек ищет наилучшее целочисленное решение путём решения неравенств в целых числах. Это несложно. Почитайте.

Метод Гомори довольно универсальная штука. Но кодить её будет проблемно. Я бы советовал разобраться с задачей о рюкзаке, так как решение выйдет компактнее. Но здесь не будет универсального решения. Придётся изобретать небольшой велосипед.

Что касается критерия эффективности, то в качестве критерия можно минимизировать время, затрачивающееся на перевозку, либо объём груза. Либо и то, и другое. Но я бы не советовал брать и то, и другое. По крайней мере по-началу. В таком случае у Вас возникнет несколько целевых функций. А с этим работать сложнее. Кроме того, можно объединить это в нелинейный функционал. Например, минимизировать скалярное произведение векторов

(X, T) = x1 * t1 + x2 * t2 + ... + xn * tn, где X -- объём перевезённого груза, T -- время. Но в таком случае задача точного решения не будет иметь. По крайней мере, при решении методом Гомори. В такой постановке она нелинейна.

В любом случае здесь всё зависит от ваших требований. Для чего решает Ваша задача? Кому она нужна?

Как только разберётесь с этими методами. Выберете то, чего Вы хотите, а самое главное, зачем Вы это хотите, пишите сюда. Попробуем разобраться, если у Вас будут вопросы.