# Поиск оптимального набора состояний

Tags: алгоритм

## Описание проблемы

Есть множество "объектов" (в примере их два но на практике несколько тысяч)

у каждого объекта есть состояния ( в примере их будет по 3 на практике ~50)

каждое состояние характеризуется двумя показателями  ( `п` и `р`)

необходимо подобрать набор состояний при котором минимальна `сумма(п)` и `сумма(р)` не менее определенного числа X.

## Пример

```
+--------+----+------+------+----+--------+--------+
| Объект | п0 |  п1  |  п2  | р0 |   р1   |   р2   |
+--------+----+------+------+----+--------+--------+
|      1 |  0 | 1000 | 1500 |  0 | 100000 | 102000 |
|      2 |  0 | 1000 | 2000 |  0 |   2000 |   2500 |
+--------+----+------+------+----+--------+--------+
```

При минимальной сумме 102000

В данном примере видно , что оптимальным является набор состояний `(2,0)`
`сумма(п)` при этом =1500

## Попытки

1) Ранее я считал оптимальное состояние( отношение `р\п`) по каждому объекту, затем сортировал по эффективности и выбирал сумму не менее лимита.

-- приведенный пример показал, что результат не дает максимальной эффективности.

2) Думал на счет простого перебора -- получается очень медленно при 2000*50 размере матрицы

3) Думал посчитать x-best состояние для каждого объекта( первое,второе и т.д лучшее)

и затем по аналогии с 1-ым вариантом, после выбора по 1-му лучшему сравнивать второе лучшее с первым лучшим и заменять в случае если эффективность растет.

-- не знаю как правильно сформулировать это и как останавливаться что бы не перебирать все варианты.

Хотелось бы увидеть идеи как можно наиболее оптимально решить  данную проблему. ( время важно, но +- час ничего не решает)

+вариант решение в R или vba был бы идеален.

## PS

состояния обладают следующими свойствами :

1) `р(i)=f(п(i))` - р зависит от п , но зависимость не известна.

2) `p(0)=0` `п(0)=0` - в нуле п и р == 0

3) `п(i+1)>п(i)` -- п растет при росте номера состояния

4) `p(i+1)>=p(i)` -- р не уменьшается при росте номера состояния( росте п)

Comment: Итоговая эффективность должна быть максимальна по каждому объекту независимо? Либо эта эффективность должна быть максимальной для всех объектов? Что делать, если для разных объектов максимальная эффективность достигается при разной комбинации состояний?

Comment: @hedgehogues Добавил ответы, надеюсь стало понятней.

Comment: я правильно понимаю задачу, что формально, нужно сделать 2000*50 делений и найти максимум?

Comment: @KoVadim матрица 2000*50 это объекты * состояния , то есть нужно выбрать вектор размером 2000 ( где каждая цифра это номер состояния для каждого объекта) так что бы эффективность рассчитанная при данном векторое была максимальна . то есть если решать перебором( в лоб) то в указанно примере( 2*3) нужно перебрать состояния(Объект1,Объект2):  (0,0);(0,1);(1,0);(0,2);(2,0);(1,1);(1,2);(2,1);(2,2) для каждого посчитать эффективность как сумма(р) /сумма(п) и выбрать лучший набор.

Comment: @KoVadim То есть при матрице 2000*50 количество комбинаций = 50^2000 ( что считается очень долго перебором в лоб)

Comment: Это очень похоже на задачу об упаковке рюкзака. Но нужно подумать глубже.

Comment: @KoVadim Возможно, почитаю завтра об этой задаче по подробнее. спасибо!

Comment: @Batanichek я буквально сегодня отвечал на вопрос про задачу о рюкзаке и методе Гомори. Если хотите, гляньте [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/310307/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/509676#509676). Я подумаю над Вашей задачей сегодня-завтра.

Comment: @Batanichek как у Вас получилось "В данном примере видно , что оптимальным является набор состояний (2,0) сумма(п) при этом =1500", 1500? сумма(п) = 1500 + 2000. Т.е. сумма по всем состояниям. Или я не правильно понимаю слово сумма, т.е. не то суммирую.

Comment: @hedgehogues п0= 0 всегда, то есть сумма п= п2( 1 объект)+п0(2объект) =1500+0.. (2,0) - вектор состояний ( 1-ый объект второе состояние и 2-ой объект нулевое состояние)

Comment: @Batanichek т.е. у каждого объекта только одно состояние, верно?

Comment: @hedgehogues да, нужно выбрать одно состояние для каждого объекта , так что бы сумма р не меньше чем X и сумма п минимальна, это очень похоже на обратный рюкзак ( но я не могу придумать как учесть что у каждого объекта только одно состояние может быть)